# apache 301 redirect can i hide url from message

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have set 301 redirection for certain URL and I don't want this message
is there any way to remove URL from this message  or just set custom message.
which is showing in response of curl

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://example.com/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at x.x.x.x Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf` and set:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```